# Bitcoin "Quits unexpectedly" everytime but only on my account

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core, mtgox

Everytime i try to open Bitcoin QT it quits unexpectedly, however if i log out and log in using another account on the same Mac, it works fine.  Can i use the other account (where my Bitcoin QT opens fine) to transfer bitcoins to from MtGox as it is still the same computer or do have to fix this issue of it quitting all the time?

Comment: Do you have funds on your account, or is it empty?

Answer (score 1):

I expect this has something to do with the file permissions. Your own user does not appear to have read/write access to the wallet or blockchain directory. Simply copy them to a location that is accessible by both of you, or change the permissions to allows your own user access.